# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression type 'object' for Object Array returned from NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, iteration

I've got a NHibernate query called in my C# code that returns an an Object Array which seems to work fine except when I try to iterate over the items in the array to use the values.  When I try a foreach over them, I get an exception:

`Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'`.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
        var counts =
            GetSession().CreateQuery(
                @"select Name, count(Id) from
                                    Account
                                    group by Name")
                .Enumerable();

        foreach (var count in counts)
        {
            string s = count[0];
        }
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to iterate over the results of the Enumerable returned?

Comment: this is issue is not related to NH, rather to c# knowledge, as this is a compilation error. see the Jon's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably the `Enumerable` method is either just returning `IEnumerable`, or `IEnumerable<object>`. Either way, the implicit typing of `count` is giving you `object` which you presumably don't want. I suspect you want something like:

```
// Giving count an explicit type tells the compiler to insert a cast.
// Obviously this will fail if it's *not* an array of some reference type.
foreach (object[] count in counts)
{
    string s = (string) count[0];
}
```

Comment: the Query will return IEnumerable which contains object[]